# Found multiple matches for field 'Order Line'

Tags: csv, import, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am trying to import data from csv into `Order_line` form and i am seeing this warning

```
Found multiple matches for field 'Order Line' (2 matches) between rows 2 and 6 (4 more)
  Found multiple matches for field 'Order Line' (2 matches) between rows 2 and 6
  Found multiple matches for field 'Order Line' (2 matches) between rows 2 and 6
  Found multiple matches for field 'Order Line' (2 matches) between rows 2 and 6
  Found multiple matches for field 'Order Line' (2 matches) between rows 2 and 6
```

and due to this all of the order_lines are being create against same user, but if you see my csv's first column which is account_number. We have two different columns.

**CSV**

```
customer/account_number,customer/first_name,customer/last_name,customer/account_type,order/transaction_id,order/product_code,order/quantity
1160925,Charles L.,Richards,Segregated,10981036,G108P70NG,50
1160925,Charles L.,Richards,Segregated,10981037,G108P70NG,150
1160925,Charles L.,Richards,Segregated,10981038,G108P70NG,250
1160925,Charles L.,Richards,Segregated,10981039,G11270NG,350
1160243,"Tracy A., Jr.",Tolar,Segregated,23231554,G108P70NG,750
```

**Note**

Order in csv header is actually `order_line` behind the scene we just renamed it in csv template for client.

**Order_line Create Method**

```py
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    product_id = False
    product_code = vals.get('product_code')
    if product_code:
        product = self.env['amgl.products'].search([
            ('product_code', '=', product_code)
        ])
        if product:
            product_id = product[0].id
        vals.update({
            'products': product_id,
        })
    record = super(OrderLine, self).create(vals)
    if (float(record['total_received_quantity']) > float(record['quantity'])):
        record.state = 'pending'
    return record
```

**Order Line Model**

```py
class OrderLine(models.Model):
_name = 'amgl.order_line'
_description = 'Order Lines'

name = fields.Char()
customer_id = fields.Many2one('amgl.customer', string='Customer Name',
                              default=lambda self: self._context.get('customer_id', False),required=True)
```

**Import Model**

```py
class CustodianDataImport(models.Model):
_name = 'amgl.custodian_data_import'
_description = 'Custodian Data Import'

customer = fields.One2many('amgl.customer', 'custodian_import_id', string='Customer')
order = fields.One2many('amgl.order_line', 'custodian_import_id', string='Order Line')
```

This model above is the separate model where I am doing the import and from this model all the order against a customer should be created.

Comment: Are you trying to import customer data from the order line directly? Are you using the method that we told you in the other question creating new dummy fields or a new Transient model?

Comment: If you are overriding the create method to create the order lines then verify that the customer is not duplicated in the database

Comment: Please add the create method to the question to check if it is right

Comment: Please see my question update, I added all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you are doing this:

```py
product = self.env['amgl.products'].search([
    ('product_code', '=', product_code)
])
if product:
    product_id = product[0].id
```

You need to create a constraint making the `product_code` unique in the database. If not you would have problems with duplicates

I suggest you to create a model and add the field that you want to import as you already have done, but it should be a `TransientModel` because it is only an auxiliar model and you are not interested in store anything in it.

On the other hand I think you shouldn't override the `create` method of the original `order_line` model. Just add everything you need in the create method of the auxiliar model like this:

```py
class OrderLineImport(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'order.line.import'

    customer_name = fields.Char(
        string='Customer',
    )

    product_code = fields.Char(
        string='Product Code',
    )

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        product_code = vals.get('product_code', False)
        customer_name = vals.get('customer_name', False)

        product_id = self._get_product_id(product_code)
        customer_id = self._get_customer_id(customer_name)

        order_line = {
            'product_id': product_id,
            'customer_id': customer_id
        }
        self.env['amgl.order_line'].create(order_line)   # the important create

        # You can create records of the model order.line.import as well, but they are going to disappear
        # because it is a transient model. I think that this is good to keep your database clean

        return super(OrderLineImport, self).create(vals)

    def _get_product_id(self, product_code):
        if product_code:
            product = self.env['amgl.products'].search([
                ('product_code', '=', product_code)
            ])
            if len(product) == 1:
                return product.id
            elif len(product) == 0:
                raise Warning(_('Product code not found: %s') % product_code)
            else:
                raise Warning(_('More than one product_code found: %s') % product_code)
        else:
            return False

    def _get_customer_id(self, customer_name):
        if customer_name:
            customer = self.env['amgl.customer'].search([
                ('name', '=', customer_name)
            ])
            if len(customer) == 1:
                return customer.id
            elif len(product) == 0:
                raise Warning(_('Customer not found: %s') % customer_name)
            else:
                raise Warning(_('More than one customer found: %s') % customer_name)
        else:
            return False
```